# Firebase cloud function first invocation after deploy always timeout

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I deployed a HTTP cloud function for firebase. However after deploy, the very first invocation returns a timeout error code. I'm using volley library for Android to invoke the HTTP function.
Subsequent invocations seem to work perfectly.

What I've done: I felt the issue maybe a cold start time problem however I tried increasing the timeout duration from code to 180secs. Yet I still get the same issue

Code: Shows the complete cloud function with the issue

```
const runtimeOptsActivateApp = {
  timeoutSeconds: 180,
  memory: '128MB'
}

exports.activateApp = functions.runWith(runtimeOptsActivateApp).https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const pin = req.query.pin;
  const id_token = req.query.auth;
  let docId;
  let uid;
  let email;

  // idToken comes from the client app
  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(id_token)
  .then(decodedToken => {
    uid = decodedToken.uid;
    email = decodedToken.email;

    return activationPinsRef
      .where("pin", "==", pin)
      .get()

  })
  .then(querySnapshot=>{
    if(querySnapshot.empty){
      return Promise.reject(new Error("Activation pin does not exist..."))
    }

    return activationPinsRef
      .where("pin", "==", pin)
      .where("is_blocked", "==", false)
      .get()

  })
  .then(querySnapshot=>{
    if(querySnapshot.empty){
      return Promise.reject(new Error("User has been blocked..."))
    }

    return activationPinsRef
      .where("pin", "==", pin)
      .where("is_blocked", "==", false)
      .where("has_activated", "==", false)
      .get()

  })
  .then(querySnapshot=>{
    if(querySnapshot.empty){
      console.log("User has activated, He may be trying to reactivate, verify his activation status in users document!")
      return usersRef
        .doc(uid)
        .get()
    }

    console.log("User is a trying to activate for the first time!")
    querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
      docId = documentSnapshot.id;
    })
    return activationPinsRef
      .doc(docId)
      .update({
        "has_activated": true,
        "uid_activated": uid,
        "time_activated": Date.now()
      })

  })
  .then(result => {

    if(result instanceof admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot){
      var is_activated = result.data().is_activated;
      if(is_activated){
        console.log('Reactivation successful!!!');
        return res.status(200).send({
          "status": "success",
          "is_reactivation": true
        })
      }
      return Promise.reject(new Error("User is_activated field is false!"))
    }

    usersRef
      .doc(uid)
      .update({
        is_activated:true
      })

    return res.status(200).send({
      "status": "success",
      "is_reactivation": false
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    return res.status(401).end()
  })

});
```

Comment: Cold starts don't result in a timeout.  The overhead of a cold start for an HTTP function is a few milliseconds, plus whatever time it takes to load and parse your JavaScript (another few milliseconds).  if you get a timeout, that means your function probably just didn't send a response before the timeout was up.  You have so much code here that it's hard to tell what situation might cause that. Add more comprehensive logging to figure out what happened.

Comment: Ok Doug, I'd add more logs. But the issue does not occur during subsequent invocations only at the first invocation

Comment: So, what do the logs say on a request that times out? Please edit the question to show the result.

Comment: A wild guess ... when you deploy a Cloud Function, that is an asynchronous request.  This Cloud Function is not necessarily "there" until a short while after GCP has received the deployment request.  In your tests, (and just as a test), after a deployment wait a couple of minutes before sending the first request.  Does this change the story at all?